# python Crypto AES cipher decode type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycrypto

I'm having a little problem using AES_CBC cipher decode function. When I assume (via a file open(x,'wb')) its return is bytes, python complains about getting a string in the write() function. When I assume (open(x,'w')) its return is string, python complains about getting bytes in the write() function. Can anyone please explain the issue here? (Python 3.5.1 for reference on Win7)

```
def decrypt(in_file, out_file, key,iv):
bs = AES.block_size
cipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CBC,iv)
next_chunk = ''
finished = False
while not finished:
    try:
        chunk, next_chunk = next_chunk, cipher.decrypt(in_file.read(bs))
    except ValueError:
        finished = True
    out_file.write(chunk)

with open(in_filename, 'rb') as in_file, open(out_filename, 'wb') as out_file:
    decrypt(in_file, out_file, key, iv)
```

Results in

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Changing the file opening statement to

```
with open(in_filename, 'rb') as in_file, open(out_filename, 'w') as out_file:
decrypt(in_file, out_file, key, iv)
```

Results in

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

The best I could do is cast the chunk to string with str(chunk),
but then my output file is a bunch of byte strings like

```
b", 'Shutdown', 'R"b"eboot', 'SetPowe"b"rSave'} (string "
```

Any thoughts? What am I doing wrong here? FYI the file was encrypted on a Fedora PC using CryptoPP. When I decode it in CryptoPP everything works out ok, but this is my first time working with pycrypto.

Comment: Have you tried `out_file.write(chunk.decode("utf-8"))` when opening the output file just with "w"?

Comment: I'm away from my work PC right now, but I'm pretty sure I did try that and got an error saying that there was no decode method. I think I also remember IntelliSense just showing the .encode() method (using PTVS in VS2015).

Comment: FYI, the problem seems to be 3.5 specific. I create a new environment using `conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda` , set VS2015 to use that, and then the code worked fine with just a 'wb' file and `out_file.write(chunk)`. I'm going to re-post my original question (plus my successful attempt in 2.7) on pycrypto's github, since it seems that I may have done it right and it could be a 3.5 related issue.